# Checking validity of an expression that contains nested parentheses by using stack

Tags: python, stack

I want to use the stack for checking the validity of an expression that contained nested parentheses.
I wrote bellow code but when my input is [{[]}, the code doesn't return anything but I expected to return "left parentheses are more than right ones".
also when my input is (), the response instead of being "balanced" is "mismatched" !!
what is my mistake in the written code?

```
class Stack:       
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, data):
        self.items.append(data)
        return

    def pop(self):
        self.items.pop()

def match(left, right):
    if left == '[' and right == ']':
        return True
    elif left == '{' and right == '}':
        return True
    elif left == '(' and right == ')':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def validity(text):
    st = Stack()

    for i in text:
        if i in '[{(':
            st.push(i)
        if i in ']})':
            if st.is_empty():
                print('right parentheses is more than left one')
                return False
            else:
                compare = st.pop()
                if not match(compare, i):
                    print('mismatched')
                    return False

    if st.is_empty():
        print('balanced')
    else:
        print('left parentheses are more than right ones')

for j in range(4):
    example = input('plz enter text ')
    validity(example)
```

Comment: Your `validity` function is not very coherent: sometimes it returns a boolean, sometimes it prints something. You should clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

`st.pop()` doesn't return anything so compare is always `None`.

```
def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()
```

Should fix it.